# Referencing other classes in a class - php

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

Say I have two php classes - class `Security` and class `Database`

**Security**

```
class Security {
    public function userPermissions() {
        //use getData() from Database to obtain information 
    }
}
```

**Database**

```
class Database { 
    public function getData() {
        // some code 
        }
    }
```

The security class needs to get data using the database class, there are many ways of achieving this but am not sure of best practice.

Is it better to do create an instance of both like;

```
$db = new Database;
$sec = new Security($db);
```

and then in the Security class use a constructor to pass the instance of the db to it?

Or would you create a new instance in the __constructor method within the security class?

I'd be grateful for any best practice.

Comment: My personal opinion is make getData() protected and use inheritance and access it by security class constructor

Comment: use the Reflection CLass API of PHP this api will do the trick for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create an instance of both and then in the Security class use a constructor to pass the instance of the db to it

The approach you described is called [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and it is generally better solution for your case from the architectural point of view.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.